# Add simultaneously a character and a string on ylab in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a list `plotDat` of 23 df and I am creating and exporting graphs for each data frame using `ggplot`, `lapply` and an anonymous function. For each df, the graph represents the column Concentration (Y axis) versus the column Year (X axis).

```
pdf("Plots.pdf")
lapply(names(plotDat), function(i){
  ggplot(plotDat[[i]], aes(Year, Concentration, group = Chemicals, col = Chemicals)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point() +
    ggtitle(paste("", i)) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = round(seq(min(Data_total$Year), max(Data_total$Year), by = 1),1)) +
    xlab("Year") +
    ylab("Concentration in (Mol/L or Mol/Kg)") 
})
dev.off()
```

The issue is, depending on the df, the concentration is given in two different units (Mol/L and Mol/Kg). Each df has a column named Unit with either Mol/L or Mol/Kg. Now, I add in `ggplot ... ylab("Concentration in (Mol/L or Mol/Kg)")` but it is not rigorous and I wish to obtain the right unit in `ylab` for each plot.

My question is : is it possible to add simulatenosuly in `ylab` a string *"concentration in"* and a character that represents `plotDat$Unit[[i]]` in `ggplot` ?

`ylab(plotDat$Unit[i])` did not work actually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming *Unit* column would have many rows with the same value, we just need to get one of them, `[ 1 ]`:

```
ylab(paste("Concentration in", plotDat[[ i ]]$Unit[ 1 ]))
```

Or we can use *unique*:

```
ylab(paste("Concentration in", unique(plotDat[[ i ]]$Unit)))
```

Reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)

plotDat <- split(iris, iris$Species)

res <- lapply(names(plotDat), function(i){
  ggplot(plotDat[[ i ]], aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
    geom_point() +
    ylab(paste("Concentration in", plotDat[[ i ]]$Species[ 1 ]))
  })

res[[ 1 ]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works perfectly! But I do not really understand why you need to add "[ 1 ]" in "Unit [ 1 ]"

Comment: @Sylvain as the Unit column would have many rows, we just need to get one of them. I assume within dataframe Unit column same value is repeated for each row.

Comment: yes it is the case, each df has only one character for $Unit. And the case there 2 different characters, may I ask you how to deal with this situation ?

Comment: @Sylvain I'd say convert all to the same unit within a dataframe based on majority? But you better post this new requirement as a new question. If you have 10 values with Mol/L and 10 values with Mol/Kg, how do you decide which one to use?

Comment: you were right, it is not a matter of plots and graphs but rather how to deal with different data in your df. Anyway, thanks a lot!